# howto realise a query which makes a second query to count the sum?

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have a problem designing a SQLite query, i have two tabels, the first is:

```
first: id, name
```

and the second

```
second: id, first_id, name
```

now i have entries in first and the entries of second always have a id from first in the `first_id` field. now i want to get all the names from the first table PLUS the count of entries with the first_id same as the if in the first table.

how to realize such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT first.name, (
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM second
 WHERE second.first_id=first.id
) as entries
FROM first
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join the tables together, and `group by` on rows in the first table:

```
select  first.id
,       first.name
,       count(*)
from    first
left join
        second
on      first.id = second.first_id
group by
        first.id
,       first.name
```